# Removing css class from element when visible in container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have the following html containers:

```
<div id="holder">
    <div class="element new">Content</div>
    <div class="element new">Content</div>
    <div class="element new">Content</div>
    <div class="element new">Content</div>
    <div class="element new">Content</div>
    <div class="element new">Content</div>
    <div class="element new">Content</div>
    <div class="element new">Content</div>
    <div class="element new">Content</div>
    <div class="element new">Content</div>
    <div class="element new">Content</div>
    <div class="element new">Content</div>
    <div class="element new">Content</div>
    <div class="element new">Content</div>
    <div class="element new">Content</div>
</div>
```

The holder container has a max-height of 300px. The element containers have an average height of 50px.
The task is now to remove the "new" class from one element container at a time whenever this container hits the top of the holder container.
I have tried several ways with javascript and jquery but none of them are working.
Here is my current function

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#holder').scroll(function() {
        var s = $(".element");
        s.each(function() {
            var pos = s.position();
            var windowpos = $('holder').scrollTop();
            if (windowpos >= pos.top & windowpos <=100) {
                s.removeClass("new");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The problem is, that this will remove the class from all of the element containers. Is there a way to remove the class from only the element that hits the top of the holder container?

Comment: By the top you mean at first child of holder element? Or visually its at the top of the page?

Comment: I meant visually at the top of the parent container.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I correctly understand your question, this should solve it:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#holder').scroll(function() {
        var s = $(".new");
        s.each(function(index, element) {
            var pos = $(element).position();
            var windowpos = $('#holder').scrollTop();
            if (windowpos >= pos.top & windowpos <=100) {
                $(s[0]).removeClass("new");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Another problem was, you forgot the `#` before `holder`.